# Netbeans Android - Compile & Test on real device (Unix, OSX)

Tags: android, testing, deployment, netbeans, integration-testing

I've read several questions about testing android apps on device.
I know possibility to upload APK to web storage, allow unsigned apps and run it
I've read some solutions using Eclipse
I've read about installing `apk` through `adb`
But nothing about Netbeans.

So **Is there some automated solution for OSX/UNIX systems and Netbeans?**

Note, I'm currently using OSX 1.7 and Netbeans 7.0 with NBAndroid plugin, but question is related to Unix/OSX in common and Netbeans since 6.5 (or lower if it supports)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will lay down answer myself, since nobody answered and I fugured it out:

1. Edit your Android manifest due to this manual:
     http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

   `<application android:debuggable="true" ... >`
2. run `./adb start-server` or `ddms` from your android sdk to enable adb server
3. On your device set `USB Debugging mode` to enabled, and connect your device to computer via USB
4. run `./adb devices` from within `/platform-tools` folder
    to view if your device is enabled correctly and visible to adb
5. run project in Netbeans (F6) and select your device in top half of window (in section `running devices`)
6. your app should be running properly on your real device, to see logs, you can use

   1. `./platform-tools/adb logcat` -> debug messages in console
   2. `./tools/ddms` -> gui to debug messages

Comment: Thanks for this, helped a lot. It seems to be a little out of date now as the `ddms` has been deprecated for the use of `monitor` and USB Debugging mode has to be activated *before* `monitor` is run. Might be worth noting that before running `monitor` your likely going to need to install a USB driver if your running NetBeans on anything other than a Mac.